# Is there something like Codecademy for Java

Tags: java

Does anyone know of a site like [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com) that focuses on teaching programming with Java? (Codeacademy.com uses guided lessons in JavaScript, HTML and CSS, and Python)

Comment: What is Codecademy? Can you describe it? Link to it?

Comment: I just started making one: http://www.learneroo.com/courses/11

Comment: This is the closest I've found so far: http://www.learnjavaonline.org/

Comment: Codecademy now does Java ! :) https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-java

Answer (score 19):

Check out [CodingBat](http://codingbat.com/)!  It really helped me learn java way back when (although it used to be JavaBat back then).  It's a lot like Codecademy.

Comment: I've found CodingBat really useful too but since CodeAcademy has guided lessons, starts at the very beginning and the pace is slower I would not say they are really alike each other.

Comment: @madth3, I'm trying to address some of that on my new site: learneroo.com/courses/11

Answer (score 4):

Check out javapassion, [they have a number of courses that encompass web programming](http://www.javapassion.com/portal/web-programming-basics-with-passion/web-programming-basics-with-passion), and were free (until circumstances conspired to make the website need to support itself).

Even with the nominal fee, you get *a lot* for an entire year.  It's a bargain compared to the amount of time you'll be investing.

The other options are to look to Oracle's online tutorials, they lack the glitz of Codeacademy, but are surprisingly good.  I haven't read the one on web programming, that might be embedded in the Java EE tutorial(s), which is not tuned for a new beginner to Java.

Answer (score 2):

As of right now, I do not know of any.  It appears the code academy folks have set their sites on Ruby on Rails.  They [do not rule Java out of the picture](http://blog.codeacademy.org/post/9556209193/will-you-ever-have-a-code-academy-for-c-or-java) however.

Comment: I suspect the OP referred to [codeacademy.com](http://www.codecademy.com) which teaches programming using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

Compilr seems to be going in that direction: http://compilr.com/teachers

Comment: I don't see using compilr as a teching tool as the same direction as having prepared courses to learn programming.